# Batch blur images using multiple cores

Tags: r, terminal, parallel-processing, imagemagick

I'm trying to blur the bottom section of thousands (>50,000) of images using imagemagick. Image resolution is 800x600. The command line code (below) works, but takes a long time. Is there any way that this can be run in parallel, and hopefully called from within R using system()?

I got this code off the internet, so I'm not sure if it's the best way to even achieve this objective? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

(OS = OSX El Capitan)

```
cd /Users/Desktop/test_images
list=$(ls *.jpg)
for img in $list; do
    convert $img \
    \( -size 800x525 xc:black -size 800x75 xc:white -append \) \
    -compose blur -define compose:args=6 -composite \
    cd /Users/Desktop/test_images/results/$img
done
cd
```

Comment: Have a look at [this Entry about running parallel jobs and waiting for them to finish with bash](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19543185/3828957). You could rewrite your script such that it starts *#cpu* jobs (or *#cpu+1*) and waits until they finish. If the jobs workload is evenly distributed, chance is high that it will give a good speedup. That would be pure bash thought and not flexible if you want to run it on other systems with more/less cores.

Comment: Please provide a sample image of the correct dimensions and also another showing the expected result.

Comment: @Mark Setchell - an original sample image can be downloaded here (https://www.dropbox.com/sh/3bnwmnklslo2shu/AABxDW-MeyAmBzspiSiV6HmFa?dl=0), and the blurred result here (https://www.dropbox.com/sh/uwadeuc7rohq1d7/AAAbT79z2f34O4z8hKv1jqbWa?dl=0).

Comment: you don't need to run a system command with the new `magick` package. Try that with R parallel ops.

Comment: Thanks @hrbrmstr. I didn't realise there was a magick package, very happy about this! I'll have a look at this asap, but for now, Mark's solution is fantastic. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this command does something very similar to what you are doing but is FAR quicker. See if you like the effect:

```
convert start.jpg \( +clone -crop +0+525 -blur x4 \) -gravity south -composite result.jpg
```

[image]

If that works, you can use **GNU Parallel** just as before:

```
parallel 'convert {} \( +clone -crop +0+525 -blur x4 \) -gravity south -composite results/{}' ::: *.jpg
```

You can also put that lot in a script called `BlurTitle` like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
parallel 'convert {} \( +clone -crop +0+525 -blur x4 \) -gravity south -composite results/{}' ::: *.jpg
```

and then make it executable with:

```
chmod +x BlurTitle
```

and call it from `R` with:

```
system("./BlurTitle")
```

or from the Terminal with:

```
./BlurTitle
```

If you get "Argument list too long", you can express it the other way around like this by sending the arguments on `stdin` rather than after the command:

```
cd /path/to/images
find . -name \*.jpg -print0 | parallel -0 'convert {} \( +clone -crop +0+525 -blur x4 \) -gravity south -composite results/{}'
```

Comment: Brilliant solution. It's extremely fast. Thanks so much!

Comment: For others who may find this useful, Mark's GNU Parallel reference refers to a similar post, which can be accessed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40035067/batch-resize-images-in-parallel-using-r/40042268#40042268

Comment: there appears to be a limit to the number of images this code will work on. I've just attempted it with 29,000 images and I get the following error: -bash: /usr/local/bin/parallel: Argument list too long